# How to correctly delete libertine containers on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libertine

So if I list libertine containters and then try to destroy some I get an error message suggesting that the container doesn't exist.

Is the list command faulty or the destroy command?

**listing containers**

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ libertine-container-manager list
puritine
vivid2
```

**trying to destroy one container**

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ libertine-container-manager destroy -i vivid2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/libertine-container-manager", line 857, in <module>
args.func(args)
  File "/usr/bin/libertine-container-manager", line 430, in destroy
destroy_container_by_id(args.id)
  File "/usr/bin/libertine-container-manager", line 416, in destroy_container_by_id
    container = LibertineContainer(id)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libertine/Libertine.py", line 287, in __init__
from  libertine.LxcContainer import LibertineLXC
ImportError: No module named 'libertine.LxcContainer'
```

**listing containers again**

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ libertine-container-manager list
puritine
vivid2
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of Ubuntu Touch (OTA-12)?  It may already have been fixed.

Comment: Yep, I am on OTA-12. I will look at filing a bug, and I will include the workaround that eDiviser gives below.

Comment: Filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/libertine/+bug/1609086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the error occurred because I had earlier tried to create lxc containers and the Ubuntu-touch kernel doesn't currently support this.

Details on https://bugs.launchpad.net/libertine/+bug/1609086

eDevise and Bjarne Roß both give working methods to destroy containers in their answers. The most 'correct' way is the following syntax

```
libertine-container-manager destroy -i container_name
```

As outlined in the bug comments this isn't an issue that should affect users from now on.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the containers you sould delete the /home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container directory and all of your container should be gone. If you want to remove the userdata from the containers too you should delete the /home/phablet/.local/share/libertine-container directory as well. In the non "...-container" folders there are config files for libertine itself you also can delete, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think there should be a libertine-container command however.

Answer (score 1):

To delete/destroy a container with the ID 'vivid2' I did the fallowing:

1. Select the vivid2 container, which shall be destroied:

   `libertine-container-manager set-default --id vivid2`.
2. Destroy the selected container:

   `libertine-container-manager destroy`